# Blender rigging problem. "Track To" contraint in bone doesn't follow the target

Tags: animation, constraints, blender

I'm working on a character whose eye balls I'm trying to rig. The method I'm using is: one bone inside the eye with a "Track To" constraint targeting a second bone right next to it, and a third bone controlling the 2 bones with no constraint (one for each eye).

The thing is that I can't make it work. The constraint's symbol is in red color, like in this link (up left) when the track axis and Up are with the same axis (e.g. track axis: -Y, Y). When they are different, like X, Y then the constraint symbol changes to white color and works ok, but it's not what I want because eye is bad oriented.

My question is, why is this happening and any ideas how can I fix it? Or more importantly, how do you make this constraint work. Maybe I'm doing it wrong. Basically I select one bone with shift, another one that it will have the constraint, then I press Ctrl + Shift + c to put the constraint, select the armature and the target bone and that's it.

Thank you.